# How to delete a row from a table in SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have done this and it is not working. I am getting `force close`.

```
public boolean favoriteDelete(int id) {
    return database.delete("FavoriteData", "Google" + "=" + id, null) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can simply use sql query to delete.

```
public void delete(String id) {
        db.execSQL("delete from "+TBL_NAME+" where Google='"+id+"'");
    }
```

In your query you are passing null in place of whereArgs

```
db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs)
```

It should be like this

```
db.delete(TBL_NAME, "Google=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
public boolean favoriteDelete(int id) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +  "=" + id, null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I know what is the difference in your answer and the question of the user?

Answer (score 4):

```
database.delete("tablename", "column_name=?", new String[] {Integer.toString(id)});
```

- the where condition values should be given as a string array

Answer (score 1):

add single quotes in your where clause...

```
return database.delete("FavoriteData", "Goggle" + "='" + id+"'", null) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use placeholders than string manipulation. Ok for int's but as soon as you put a string in there things will go wrong.

```
String where = COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = { String.valueOf(address) };

SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_NAME_DEVICES, where, whereArgs);
```